# Changing Class whit jQuery not works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<div id="dowload">
    <a class="got player-frame btn btn-info" href="#" title="watch">
     <i class="icon-white icon-play"></i></a>
    <a class="download-frame btn btn-success" href="#" title="download">
     <i class="icon-white icon-download-alt"></i> Download</a>
</div>
```

I need ONCLICK class **got**, change the class **icon-play** to **icon-pause**

Im using this code, but not works.

```
        $('a.got').click(function() {
            $('i.icon-white').parent().toggleClass('icon-pause');
        });
```

Comment: Where is the '.mp3z' class? And why not just target the '.btn' class itself rather than target its child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We dont have any icons over here so I am changing colour of the background to demonstrate toggling of your desired classes.

```js
$('.got').on('click',function(){
       $(this).find('.icon-white').toggleClass('icon-play icon-pause');
  
});
```

```css
.icon-white{
  margin:0px 20px;
  
  }

.icon-play{    
   background:#ddd;    
}

.icon-pause{
     background:#fdc847;
}

a{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#999;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dowload">
    <a class="got player-frame btn btn-info" href="#" title="watch">
     <i class="icon-white icon-play">yourIcon</i>click here (anchor tag having got class)</a>
    <a class="download-frame btn btn-success" href="#" title="download">
     <i class="icon-white icon-download-alt"></i> Download</a>
</div>


<div class="dowload">
    <a class="got player-frame btn btn-info" href="#" title="watch">
     <i class="icon-white icon-play">yourIcon</i>click here (anchor tag having got class)</a>
    <a class="download-frame btn btn-success" href="#" title="download">
     <i class="icon-white icon-download-alt"></i> Download</a>
</div>

<div class="dowload">
    <a class="got player-frame btn btn-info" href="#" title="watch">
     <i class="icon-white icon-play">yourIcon</i>click here (anchor tag having got class)</a>
    <a class="download-frame btn btn-success" href="#" title="download">
     <i class="icon-white icon-download-alt"></i> Download</a>
</div>

<div class="dowload">
    <a class="got player-frame btn btn-info" href="#" title="watch">
     <i class="icon-white icon-play">yourIcon</i>click here (anchor tag having got class)</a>
    <a class="download-frame btn btn-success" href="#" title="download">
     <i class="icon-white icon-download-alt"></i> Download</a>
</div>

<div class="dowload">
    <a class="got player-frame btn btn-info" href="#" title="watch">
     <i class="icon-white icon-play">yourIcon</i>click here (anchor tag having got class)</a>
    <a class="download-frame btn btn-success" href="#" title="download">
     <i class="icon-white icon-download-alt"></i> Download</a>
</div>

<div class="dowload">
    <a class="got player-frame btn btn-info" href="#" title="watch">
     <i class="icon-white icon-play">yourIcon</i>click here (anchor tag having got class)</a>
    <a class="download-frame btn btn-success" href="#" title="download">
     <i class="icon-white icon-download-alt"></i> Download</a>
</div>


<div class="dowload">
    <a class="got player-frame btn btn-info" href="#" title="watch">
     <i class="icon-white icon-play">yourIcon</i>click here (anchor tag having got class)</a>
    <a class="download-frame btn btn-success" href="#" title="download">
     <i class="icon-white icon-download-alt"></i> Download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This code works perfectly, but i have 20 results (20 <div id="dowload">) and all results change the class, i need to change only in the div clicked. How can I do this ?, thanks for your reply.

Comment: this make the trick $('a.mp3z').on('click',function(){
        var location = $(this).parent().parent();
       $('.icon-white',location).toggleClass('icon-play icon-pause');
  
});

Comment: first of all you cannot have 20 divs with same id's ( id's need to be unique)...instead apply a class name download to those div's....I have modified my answer to your requirement....plz check...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a.mp3z').on('click', function() {
    if($('.icon-white').hasClass('icon-play')) {
         $('.icon-white').removeClass('icon-play').addClass('icon-pause');
    } else {
        $('.icon-white').removeClass('icon-pause').addClass('icon-play');
    }
});
```